# Error with JaCoCo test report generation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven-3, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

We have a JaCoco plugin in a pom.xml file for a Java project. When we build locally using mvn -U clean install, the local build failed due to the below error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.4.201502262128
:report (jacoco-site) on project: An error has occurred in JaCoCo Test report generation. Error while creating report: Error while analyzing class        C:\eclipse-workspace\project\target\classes\dist\tools\lib\xml-apis.jar@org/w3c/dom/DOMException.class. 
Can't add different class with same name: org/w3c/dom/DOMException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Could anyone please help us with this error. Thank you.

Comment: Either this class's java program exists in 2 locations (i.e. one in the src/main/java or src/test/java OR you have a class file (during jacoco phase) where there's no source java for it.